# How can I secure a nodemailer node js app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nodemailer

I have a react app in firebase with a contact form so I set up a node js app with nodemailer but anyone with the endpoint can use it. How can I configure it for only allowing the post request from my react app? Because the api url is shown at the sources.

Comment: You need some kind of [authentication](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/#authentication) (or for the endpoint itself).

Comment: You can use origin restricts to lock down incoming requests to that endpoint for only the domain/address hosting your react app. all others with fail for invalid CORS

Comment: CORS could be bypassed with proxy. A chrome extension can do that

Comment: I need some kind of authentication for the endpoint but there’s no login to show contact form. Is for anyone to send a message

Comment: you can't fully prevent that

Comment: You could add a token as part of the load of react-app. Then calling your endpoint, the token will need to be added. On the endpoint you can verify that the token is valid.

Comment: But the source code could reveal how the token is generated and could be replicated